# Accidentally loading angularjs multiple times causes strange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Due to dynamically loaded instances of Angular.js, I'm seeing an issue where `ng-repeat` will cube the number of items displayed.

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```html
<html ng-app="brokentable">
<head>
    <title>Broken Angular Table</title>

  <!-- the following are dynamically added by other code -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('brokentable', []);

        app.controller('BrokenTable', function($scope) {
            $scope.headings = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
            $scope.fillings = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], [7, 8, 9]];
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="BrokenTable">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="heading in headings">{{heading}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="filling in fillings">
      <td ng-repeat="fill in filling">{{fill}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

### How do I prevent Angular's JS file from being loaded multiple times, but still enable dynamically adding script references to the page?

Given that I still have the need to add the script file references to my page dynamically, what can I do to keep the issue demonstrated above from happening?

Comment: StackOverflow is a questions&answers site. This is neither a question nor answer. So, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @stewie.  I ran into a silent behavior of angular that I couldn't find any reference to, and I thought I'd share my discovery in a way that others could find it.  Please note that I added an answer below for some context.  There does not seem to be any documentation anywhere for how to check if angular is already loaded in the page.  This now can serve as a reference for that too.

Comment: @Stewie it's at least an attempt at being helpful, but it should be marked as "Community Wiki" most likely.

Comment: Thanks @blesh I'm finding that stackoverflow is where I find everything that documentation leaves out.  I wanted to contribute this back because I'm sure others will run into this problem, and it is hard to debug.

Comment: @blesh This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question, but only a statement about an already solved issue.

Comment: @Stewie, So you're saying that no one should ever post a question and an answer themselves in the spirit of being helpful to others? Why not? Because you can't get points for it? Seems silly... and wrong. Really, really wrong. I'm the on that +1'ed your comment above, btw... but it was purely accidental. I'd remove it if I could.

Comment: @blesh Seems to me you're taking this in wrong direction. All I'm saying is that question should be posted in form of question, and if it's a self-answering question, than the answer should be provided in the answers section. Otherwise, SO would be full on unanswered questions which are really not questions but statements/answers. And that's what coderwall and similar services are for.

Comment: There. A quick edit and it's a question. Pedants of the world rejoice.

Comment: The 1.3 release of AngularJS should resolve this bug (I submitted it to the issue tracker after posting this Question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to wrap your loading code for angularjs using window.angular as follows:

```
  <script>
    if (!window.angular) {
      document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"><\/script>');
    }
  </script>
```

or if you happen to be using a local copy of angular:

```
  <script>
    if (!window.angular) {
      document.write('<script src="angular.js"><\/script>');
    }
  </script>
```

This way you can avoid inadvertently loading angular twice which results in unexpected and silent side effects.